# What ferries go from Sweden to Finland?

Tags: ferries, sweden, finland, baltic-sea

I'm in Sweden and I need to go to Finland. I don't want to take a flight or drive there, and I've seen that there seem to be ferries going from Sweden to Finland.

What ferry options are there for getting from Sweden to Finland?

Comment: Where in Finland?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified the exact point of departure and arrival. But I am assuming you are leaving Stockholm for either Helsinki or Turku.

- [Viking Line](https://www.vikingline.fi) (**do NOT book through their English/International website, you can expect to pay four times the regular price if you do so**)
- [TallinK | Silja Line](https://www.tallinksilja.com)
- [St Peter Line](http://stpeterline.com)
- Finally, [Wasaline](https://www.wasaline.com/en/) operates the Vaasa-Umeå-Vaasa route.

**NOTE**: Booking a round-trip ticket and not showing up on the way back is against international regulations and at least Viking Line takes that very seriously. So do not do that just because it's cheaper to book a round-trip ticket. They might not bother you at all, but they might very well do and give you hell--that is to say, give you hefty penalties, etc.

Comment: *"against international regulations ... hefty penalties"* Say what?  Do you have a source of this?  Viking Line's own pages only state that you get no refunds if you don't use the return leg: https://www.sales.vikingline.com/my-booking/good-to-know/cancellation-refund/

Comment: Yes. I have a source. Open your email and send Viking Line an email asking the same question. I have asked them the same question about 3-4 times on different occasions and once even in person at their headquarter in Helsinki.

Comment: Of course they don't *want* you to use cheap returns instead of expensive one-ways, but I'm asking for *actual* consequences or details about these supposed "international regulations".

Comment: There is very little they can do if you don't show up for the return leg. To my knowledge not a single company in Europe does so despite however strict their official line might be. Even airlines would at worst cancel your frequent flyer account.

Comment: I don't believe Viking Line would be able to penalize you at all for doing that. None whatsoever.

Comment: The [Kilpisjärvi-Koltalahti boat](https://www.mallalaiva.com/three-country-cairn/) also runs from Finland to Sweden :-D

Answer (score 5):

Too many to sensibly summarize in an answer that would soon be out of date, but the two core routes with the best schedules, largest ferries and usually cheapest prices are **Stockholm-Helsinki** and **Stockholm-Turku**, with the two largest operators on both being [Viking Line](https://www.sales.vikingline.com/) and [Tallink Silja](https://www.tallinksilja.com/routes-and-timetables).  Direct Ferries has a [more thorough list of options](http://www.directferries.co.uk/ferries_from_finland_to_sweden.htm).

Beware that pricing is complicated, and it's often much cheaper to book a "cruise" and throw away the return than to get a regular one-way.

Comment: The list is limited and we haven't seen any changes in over 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

Adding some information about Viking line- it's free to become a member and in return you get discounts. 
Viking line also sails from Kapellskär (100km north of Stockholm) to Mariehamn which is technically Finland. You can make a round trip in half a day, and it is free for members.
The prices to Turku and Helsinki varies, but again members get good deals down to a few hundred Kronas to a family.
The catch ? they want you to buy cheap alcohol and tobacco on board.